# Interface Builder - after update fram object's position changed

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7

When set constraint for object from **SuperView**, frame needed update and after frame updated,  object's position increased to -4 from right and left but constraint equal 0.

**Xcode 7.2**

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select my ViewController and go to atribute change simulated metrics **Size** to **iPhone 5.5"**.

The problem becuase i select **Size** iPhone 3.5"